# Unexpected field 'g-recaptcha-response' in POST data on CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, recaptcha, cakephp-3.4

I have created a site using CakePHP 3. I have static page which has contact us form something like this:

inside contactus.ctp:

```
<?=$this->Form->create(); ?>
        <?=$this->Form->hidden('form_type',['value' => 'contact']) ?>
        <?=$this->Form->input('name',[
            'label' => false,
            'placeholder' => 'Your Full Name',
            'required' => true
        ]); ?>

        <?=$this->Form->input('email',[
            'label' => false,
            'placeholder' => 'Your Email',
            'type' => 'email',
            'require' => true
        ]); ?>

        <?=$this->Form->textarea('message',[
            'placeholder' => 'Your message...'
        ]) ?>

        <?= $this->Recaptcha->display()?> 

        <button>Submit Query!</button>

        <?=$this->Form->end(); ?>
```

Using the following link I created Recaptcha:

https://github.com/agiletechvn/Recaptcha

Just beside the Submit button I have Recaptcha.

[image]

In the pageController I have the submit check happening:

```
if($this->request->is(['post']) && $this->request->data('form_type') == 'contact'){

            $name = $this->request->data('name');
            $email = $this->request->data('email');
            $message = $this->request->data('message');

            if(!$name){
                $this->Flash->set('Please enter a name' . $name,['element' => 'error']);
            } elseif (!$email || filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
                $this->Flash->set('The email you entered is invalid',['element' => 'error']);
            } elseif(!$message){
                $this->Flash->set('Message cannot be blank',['element' => 'error']);
            } else {
                if($this->Recaptcha->verify()) {
                $emailObj = new Email();
                $emailObj
                    ->from(['contactus@mydomain.com' => 'Developer'])
                    ->replyTo([$email => $name])
                    ->to(['contactus@contactus.com'])
                    ->template('pages/contactus')
                    ->viewVars([
                        'quickAction' => [
                            'description' => 'Contact form',
                            'action' => "from: $name"
                        ],
                        'name' => 'contactus@mydomain.com',
                        'senderName' => $name,
                        'email' => $email,
                        'message' => $message
                    ])
                    ->subject('Contact email from ' . $name)
                    ->send();

                $this->Flash->set('Your message has been sent', ['element' => 'success']);
            }

            $this->Flash->error(__('Please pass Google Recaptcha first'));
          }
```

If I click submit button I get:

```
Unexpected field 'g-recaptcha-response' in POST data
```

I moved the reCaptcha code outside the form. Everything works correctly but the captcha but is sitting outside some random location like this:

[image]

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This message can show if you are using CakePHP Security Component, and this component does not recognize one of your form fields. You should unlock this field using:

```
$this->Form->unlockField('g-recaptcha-response');
```

More info: [CakePHP 3.x Security Component](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/security.html)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Where do you have to put this? Sorry I am totally new to cake php

Comment: Put it in .ctp file, before `$this->Form->end()`.